# Python/Selenium script for Interactin with currently active user-selected tab using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium with Python to interact with a webpage on an already running Chrome browser. The user could have multiple tabs open with the same webpage, but I want the script to only interact with the currently active tab chosen by the user. I want the script to keep the same Chrome window open and use it each time the script is run.

For testing, I have two tabs of ](https://stackoverflow.com)https://demo.guru99.com/test/radio.html. I want the script to interact with the tab that the user currently has open. However, my script currently only interacts with the first tab.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

webdriver_service = Service(r'C:\Users\cjcha\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'vfb-7-2')))
except:
    print('unable to locate element')
else:
    element.click()
```

I've enabled Chrome with remote debugging to use the same browser for the script.

Is it possible to modify this script to interact with the currently active tab, as chosen by the user?